# Is there a Python class similar to QListIterator in QT?

Tags: python, qt, list, iterator, pyqt

I need functionality similar to QListIterator such as:
next() - found ofcourse in python
peekNext()
previous()

Tried to look for a Python similar class.

Comment: no. i meant a class that is constructed with a list and there are functions like next() and previous() and peeknext() that let "peek" to the next value without advancing the iterator.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistiterator.html#details

Comment: I googled before asking and even after your answer i can guess there is no built in class in python.
i should come up with a class of my own or take others suggestions.

Comment: Please present a real use-case for such a class.

Comment: By "present a real use case", I meant provide some sample code that demonstrates why you would need such a class. My hunch is that this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174568), and so this class is not actually needed. Or to put it another way: there's probably a good reason why PyQt doesn't wrap QListIterator.

Comment: I need to traverse a sqlite joined table(firefox places.sqlite inside tables) and populate a QTreeWidget with the same bookmarks i have on my firefox.
I need this class to use recursion since the table is organized in such that after each bookmark's folder its children are listed one after another so i can get the next row and  add it to the current folder **UNLESS** that row belongs to an upper folder and so i dont want the list iterator move forward to the next row if its not a child of current folder.
I used to do the same thing with firefox bookmarksbackup json file but now its compressed.

Comment: You need to edit your question to show **real code** that demonstrates the need for the QListIterator class. Without that, this is all just hypothetical, and therefore off-topic for SO.

Comment: You are right.
Instead of `for i in someList:` that is not letting me go backwards in list,  
i can just use `someList[index]` and keep track after `index` so i can go backwards if needed.
Sorry for this discussion.
Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

That is the way i handeled it in the end.
A class based on UserList class with hasNext() method for checking if iterating forward is possible and other two for getting next value with no index increment and getting next value with index increment.
Nothing too special.

```
class BiDirectList(UserList.UserList):
"""
list with peek into next value method with no index increment
"""
def __init__(self, userList):
    super(BiDirectList, self).__init__(userList)
    self.next = 0

def hasNext(self):
    # check if next value exists
    try:
        if self.data[self.next]:  # data represent the list associated with the class object
            return True
    except IndexError:
        return False

def getNext(self):
    # gets next value and advance index in one
    val = self.data[self.next]
    self.next += 1
    return val

def peekNext(self):
    # gets next value if exists with no index increment
    return self.data[self.next]
```